# Unable to install pip on AIX system

Tags: python-2.7, pip, aix

I am trying to install python pip on AIX VM, but when I am trying I am getting so many errors. Could anyone help me into it.

## python get-pip.py

/tmp/tmpqZBZXW/pip.zip/pip/*vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl*.py:315: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
/tmp/tmpqZBZXW/pip.zip/pip/*vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl*.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /opt/freeware/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: I am using python version 2.7.5.# python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  2 2013, 23:28:11) [C] on aix6
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()

Answer (score 2):

The first URL in your question explains things pretty clearly. You've got an old python linked against probably an old openssl.

https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning

> Certain Python platforms (specifically, versions of Python earlier
>   than 2.7.9) have restrictions in their ssl module that limit the
>   configuration that urllib3 can apply. In particular, this can cause
>   HTTPS requests that would succeed on more featureful platforms to
>   fail, and can cause certain security features to be unavailable.
>
> If you encounter this warning, it is strongly recommended you:

- upgrade to a newer Python version
- upgrade ndg-httpsclient with pip
- install --upgrade ndg-httpsclient
- use pyOpenSSL as described in the OpenSSL / PyOpenSSL section

Comment: none of this works with pip 9.x: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4098